# How to populate the json data using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, ajax

I ve been trying to populate a searchable drop down list using json data with angularjs , i ve pushed the json data in the server and i ve been able to receive the response from the server if i use the get method.I dont know exactly how to query the json data and populate them in the search bar.
I ve attached the controller script and the html

```
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myctrl',function($scope,$http){
    $http({
        method:"GET",
        url:"http://localhost:5050/codes?val="}).then(function mySuccess(response){
        $scope.msg=response.data;
    },function myError(response){
        $scope.msg=response.statusText;
    });
});
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

signals

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl" >
        <select ng-model="search">
            <option ng-repeat="names in msg " value="{{names.value}}"></option>
            </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is the sample json data that i am feeding to the page from the local host
i have to populate the search bar with the "value" part of the json data.

```
{"codes":
   [{"code": "NSE/AHLWEST", "value": "Asian Hotels (West) Limited"}, 
   {"code": "NSE/JINDALSWHL", "value": "Jindal South West Holding Limited"}, 
   {"code": "NSE/WIPL", "value": "The Western India Plywoods Limited"}, 
   {"code": "NSE/WSTCSTPAPR", "value": "West Coast Paper Mills Limited"}]
 }
```

Comment: You are receiving JSON as an objects so better use `msg.codes` in your `ng-repeat` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to access the `codes` property. And also it is better to use `ng-options` rather than `ng-repeat` in this scenario

```
<select ng-model="search" ng-options="names.value as names.code for names in msg.codes"> 
</select>
```

Comment: Than you so much

Comment: @SathishSridhar No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to access **`codes`**

```
<option ng-repeat="names in msg.codes " value="{{names.value}}"></option>
```

Comment: Than you so much :)

Comment: The above code  worked better , i thought i could have multiple answers.Thanks once again :)